# How can i make this faster? Lots of arrays

Tags: python

I want to make this faster, I'm not a great coder and just want to learn. This program reads paragraphs of common artists separated by commas. The user inputs the name of a desired artist and the program searches through the paragraphs to find all related artists and sorts them into order of most common to least common. The artist text file is very large 600kb of text so perhaps thats the reason its slow.

```
class ArtistSuggester:
fileName = "list_of_artists.txt"
arrayOfLists = []
artist = input("Enter Artist Name: ")


@classmethod
def make_array(cls):
    # sets text to 2D-array
    f = open(cls.fileName, 'r', encoding="utf8")
    curr_par = f.read().split("\n")
    for line in curr_par:
        cls.arrayOfLists.append(line.split(","))

@classmethod
def get_locations(cls):
    # searches array for given artist and returns array with areas where the artist was found
    locations = []
    for x in range(0, len(cls.arrayOfLists)):
        for y in range(0, len(cls.arrayOfLists[x])):
            if cls.arrayOfLists[x][y] == cls.artist:
                locations.append(x)
    return locations

@staticmethod
def search_array_for_artist(the_list, artist):
    # searches given array for the given artist's name and returns the position
    # if found nothing returns negative number to symbolize non-existence
    pos = 0
    for x in range(0, len(the_list)):
        if the_list[x] == artist:
            pos = x
            break
        else:
            pos = -1
    return pos

@classmethod
def ordered_suggestion_list(cls):
    # makes the final suggestion list in correct order
    # makes two arrays, one with the names and the other with the counts of each throughout the text file.
    check = cls.get_locations()
    final_list = cls.arrayOfLists[check[0]]
    final_list.remove(cls.artist)
    count = [1] * int(len(final_list))
    for x in range(1, len(check)):
        for y in range(0, len(cls.arrayOfLists[check[x]])):
            if cls.arrayOfLists[check[x]][y] == cls.artist:
                continue
            elif cls.search_array_for_artist(final_list, cls.arrayOfLists[check[x]][y]) > 0:
                count[cls.search_array_for_artist(final_list, cls.arrayOfLists[check[x]][y])] += 1
            else:
                final_list.append(cls.arrayOfLists[check[x]][y])
                count.append(1)
    # makes a dict based off the count and names list to combine values to the keys
    combined_list = dict(zip(final_list, count))
    new_list = []
    for key, value in sorted(combined_list.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
        new_list.append(key)
    print(new_list)
```

Comment: your class is empty, you should add something to it, otherwise it will throw an error

Comment: I think your indents are off. Could your pls fix it? And if you could upload the list_of_artists.txt somewhere and post it here, we could work much better on your code.